# What's our policy on simply posting a link?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I know on SO it's generally [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/217110) and link only answers are commonly flagged and deleted.

What's the policy on this site? The same?

---

If the user summarises the link than that's a different matter. I'm talking about literally:

> You'll find the answer here http://linkonlyanswer.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links are not really good answers in the context of a Stack Exchange site. 
Your choices are to improve the post yourself, or to down-vote with a thoughtful and instructive comment to the author explaining *why* this is not a good answer — perhaps pointing them here to this thread.

**Why?** The Outdoors Stack Exchange is not a search engine or a collection of links. It's okay to add links for further reading, but this site was created to build a *definitive* collection of ***answers*** to outdoors questions.

The folks here will work hard to curate this collection of knowledge, so when someone comes looking for answers through search, **the last thing we should be doing is sending them **elsewhere**** to find that information. Showing them the door *might* seem helpful in a single instance, but ultimately link-only answers do little more than add another barrier between future readers and the *actual* information they are looking for.

That's not making the Internet better.

Answer (score 7):

I would typically downvote and comment on such answers if I see them. All reasons why those kind of answers are discouraged on most stackexchange sites, are valid here too in my opinion.

I expect at least a summary which contains an answer to the question, so that users are not forced to navigate away from this site.